# UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xd8 in position 10: invalid continuation byte

Tags: python, pandas, flask, unicode, spyder

I am running the following code in spyder

```
    df_test=pd.read_csv(request.files.get("file"))
    print(df_test.head())
    prediction=classifier.predict(df_test)
```

and getting the error

```
File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers/c_parser_wrapper.py", line 69, in __init__
    self._reader = parsers.TextReader(self.handles.handle, **kwds)
  File "pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx", line 542, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader.__cinit__
  File "pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx", line 642, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._get_header
  File "pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx", line 843, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._tokenize_rows
  File "pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx", line 1917, in pandas._libs.parsers.raise_parser_error
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xd8 in position 10: invalid continuation byte
```

Have tried other solutions also but nothing has worked.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Can you open the file in a spreadsheet program or a text editor? Do you know the file encoding? What is the encoding? Do you understand [what encoding means in this context](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2003/10/08/the-absolute-minimum-every-software-developer-absolutely-positively-must-know-about-unicode-and-character-sets-no-excuses/)? Are you familiar with [how Unicode works in Python](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/unipain.html)? Did you try reading the documentation for `pandas.read_csv` in order to understand how to handle different encodings?

Comment: Welcome back to Stack Overflow. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example. Do you need to use Spyder to run the code, in order to cause the problem? Do you need the code `prediction=classifier.predict(df_test)` in order to cause the problem? What needs to be in the CSV file in order to cause the problem? Does the question actually have anything to do with Flask - can you cause the problem by saving the file locally first and then using it?

Comment: try with: `encoding` option. Ex: `pd.read_csv(request.files.get("file"), encoding="utf-8")`

Comment: @KarlKnechtel yes it is for a flask app. I have saved the file locally and then using it.

Comment: @HarshaBiyani thanks. I have already tried but it is showing the same error.

Comment: Did you try using a different encoding? Did you try to figure out which encoding should be used? Do you understand what an encoding is?

Comment: Using different encoding helped me in a similar situation. You should google the types of encoding and then have a trial and error

Comment: Also sometimes, images in a file can also cause this error

Comment: try with different encodings: https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#standard-encodings

Comment: "I have saved the file locally and then using it." If you pulled the page off the web, why don't you provide a link?

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried passing the argument `encoding="latin-1'"` into your `read_csv`?